# Wireless connectivity problems with Qualcomm Atheros AR9287 in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 15.04, atheros

I'm having various problems. The first and less annoying is that when loading a website at first I will get the network connection error, after refreshing a few times the internet will work fine. The other issue is when downloading big files it will always fail. I'm trying to download steam games and it's downloading for 30 seconds and then disconnecting for 3 minutes and repeating.

To me it seems like the card is entering power saving mode or something similar, but I don't know. The WiFi card worked well on Windows. I'm a bit lost in ubuntu as its my first week.

```
kretash@Hephaestus:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9287 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002e] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:30a4]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

Im having the same issue. It gets frustrating after numerous disconnects. I had some success by changing the wifi router channel settings. I switched from channel 5 to 11 and is stable now for quite some time. Good Luck